# YouTube video embedding has been ENABLED for this site

Tags: discussion

By reqest of this community, direct embedding of YouTube videos has been ENABLED.

When you include a valid YouTube link on a line by itself, the video will appear in your post automatically.

There are a few caveats that go with this:

- **Videos should be used as supplemental material ONLY**
  Make sure posts don't depend on a video. The lifeblood of this site is search, and videos are black boxes without text. Make sure the post works WITHOUT the video. If the video is removed, we have no way of getting it back.
- Old  posts with video links do not embed automatically. If you re-edit a post, the video should appear.

Enjoy!

Comment: Thanks! Works great to support some questions and answers, we will make sure, as a community, to use is sparsely and wisely!

Comment: Many thanks for this.

Answer (score 5):

IMHO, I feel that we should really use this functionality only when an OP has posted a video to demonstrate a particular problem with *their own* printer... and not embed videos showing a process or video tutorial.

By embedding the former only, then this serves the immediacy of the situation, that is to say, to help the OP resolve their issue. Links to third party tutorials, product demonstrations, etc., can be watched, after clicking the link, in separate windows - at the viewer's leisure, without having to tax the back-end servers needlessly, with inline video.

Obviously exceptions will arise, but hopefully these will be kept to a minimum.

Does that sound logical?